# Java.util.Calendar compareTo not delivering consistent Results

Tags: java, android, calendar

```
public boolean checkDates(String oldDate, String newDate){
        java.util.Calendar oldCal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        java.util.Calendar newCal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        String[] oD = oldDate.split("-");
        String[] nD = newDate.split("-");
        oldCal.set(Integer.parseInt(oD[0]), Integer.parseInt(oD[1])-1, Integer.parseInt(oD[2]));
        newCal.set(Integer.parseInt(nD[0]), Integer.parseInt(nD[1])-1, Integer.parseInt(nD[2]));

        if(newCal.compareTo(oldCal) > 0){
             return true;
        }else {
             return false;
        }
```

That's the code I'm implementing with varied results for dates on the same day.  Sometimes compareTo delivers a 1 sometimes a 0.  An example print of the dates being compared:

```
oldCal Fri Nov 17 23:30:48 CST 2021
newCal Fri Nov 17 23:30:48 CST 2021
```

All of the times have been the same on both the 1 returns and the 0's.

Comment: Do not longer use the outdated Calendar API. Change to the new java.time api.

Comment: there are chances oldCal and newCal have different milliseconds

Comment: Are you **manually** parsing dates using the old Calendar API? It's 2021, time to [get with the program](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro). Oh wait, this is android. But surely it's not stuck on Calendar (or clumsy manual parsing).

Comment: I think you had it right D Blacksmith with Calendar...Have not used LocalDate before but now...Life is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
LocalDate
.parse( "2022-01-23" )
.isAfter(
    LocalDate.of( 2030 , Month.DECEMBER , 31 )
)
```

## Fractional second varies

To answer your question directly, as [commented by D Blacksmith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70015100/java-util-calendar-compareto-not-delivering-consistent-results#comment123767666_70015100), you are probably seeing two different values for the fractional second because you call  `java.util.Calendar.getInstance()` twice, two different methods.

To look at the bigger picture, you are using *terrible* date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and such.

## *java.time*

I presume you are trying to compare date-only string values in format of YYYY-MM-DD. If so, then your entire need for writing your `checkDates` method is moot.

The format of YYYY-MM-DD is actually the standard format defined by [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for textual data-exchange of date-time values. The *java.time* classes use the standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating such strings.

```
LocalDate x = LocalDate.parse( "2022-01-23" ) ;
LocalDate y = LocalDate.of( 2030 , Month.DECEMBER , 31 ) ;
```

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html), so they know how to sort themselves. And the class offers handy comparison methods: [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)), `isEqual`, and [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isAfter(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)).

```
boolean isXAfterY = x.isAfter( y ) ;
```

### Android

The *java.time* functionality is built into Android 26 and later.

For earlier Android, modern tooling brings over most of the *java.time* functionality via “API desugaring”. If that does not do the job, add the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library to your project.